# Convert numpy array to base64

Tags: python

I want to convert frame from a video file to base64 without save in directory.

I use: `img = frame.copy()` to take a frame from my video and it return a numpy array.

How can i convert it into base64 to store in database and display it into web.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `base64` library https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work - note you'll have to switch around the format as needed, and the corresponding base64 string. In this example I've used PNG.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64

data = frame.copy()

image_out = Image.fromarray(data)
buffer = BytesIO()
image_out.save(buffer, format="PNG")
base64_str = "data:image/png;base64," + base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> base64_str
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...`
```